# How to make Lenovo E440 integrated webcam work on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, lenovo, webcam

I have searched a lot of topics over the Internet, but I still can not resolve this issue.

The webcam is not detected on my Lenovo ThinkPad E440 laptop with Ubuntu 18.04. In fact, it behaves very strangely: when I restart my laptop and open Cheese application or Skype and try to test the video, webcam turns on but everything is in black and white. Then, several seconds after it turns off and never comes back. Also, I can not find the webcam in the list of my devices using `lspci` command. I tried pressing Fn + F7 to toggle the on/off state of the webcam but it didn't help. I suspect it's something with drivers. Maybe someone has already encountered such issue and can help me with it?

Thank you in advance.

[UPD]:

That's what I get by running `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
```

No webcam listed here.

Comment: You say it doesn't show in `lspci`, hmm, does it show in `lsusb`?

Comment: @AndroidDev as far as I can tell, no. I'll update the question with what I get from `lsusb`. It's an integrated webcam, so I doubt that it should appear in this list anyway.

Comment: Well, sometimes integrated sensors are on the USB bus instead of PCIe, (for example you'll notice your fingerprint sensor is on the USB bus). But in any case, I don't see anything like a webcam in either list, hrmmm....